# Encoding csv webrequest

Tags: powershell, encoding, character-encoding

[image]I'm having trouble being able to encode this request from google sheets.

```
$webresponse = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hqjD2ghx-NNV6KgHqvPSvJoE5tQk6Sm_DJqyVHTrFwU/export?format=csv"
$News = $webresponse.Content  | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
```

Anyway I spin it, The encoding isn't correct, primarily, apostrophes I noticed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I’m unclear - is the problem with ```Invoke-WebRequedt``` or ```ConvertFrom-Csv```? What *soecifically* is happening that you’re not expecting? What *are* you expecting? More details would help…

Comment: @mclayton I believe he is referring to things like `Russia’s` getting encoding issues in 5.1

Comment: I updated with a screenshot.

Comment: iceman: for reference, if you use pwsh 7 this wouldn't be a problem

Comment: You can use `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($request.RawContentStream.ToArray())` to solve your problem

Comment: OK thank you Santiago.  I see how you did this.  This is what I was missing.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The issue arises because the server encoded the response with one encoding (UTF8) in this case but Powershell uses a different one to decode it (ISO-1559-1 here) due to using different heuristics about what encoding should be assumed based on Content-Type and charset headers - the result is the euro symbol ```€``` for example gets converted to ```â¬``` (there’s 3 characters but the middle one is non-printing) - there’s various duplicates of this question around with some more details of the background…

Comment: In the absence of `charset` information in the response header, _Windows PowerShell_ assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding. _PowerShell (Core) 7.0 - 7.3.x_ does too, _except for JSON_, where UTF-8 is assumed. v7.4+ now _generally_ defaults to UTF-8. If the de-facto encoding (e.g. UTF-8) differs from the assumed one and you have no way of getting the service to include `charset` information in its response, you'll have to _manually_ decode the response using the encoding of choice, based on the response body's _raw bytes_, via `Invoke-WebRequest`, as shown in Santiago's answer and the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`[Encoding]::UTF8.GetString` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-8.0#system-text-encoding-getstring(system-byte())) to avoid these encoding issues:

```bash
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hqjD2ghx-NNV6KgHqvPSvJoE5tQk6Sm_DJqyVHTrFwU/export?format=csv'
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($request.RawContentStream.ToArray()) | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Worth noting, in PowerShell 7.4+ this isn't an issue as it defaults to UTF8 Encoding.

Comment: Nice, though the v7+ story is a bit more complicated: 7.0 - 7.3.x default to UTF-8 _for JSON only_ (for other media types it is ISO-8859-1, as it consistently is and will remain in WinPS), v7.4+ now _generally_ defaults to UTF-8